# in postgrers if you have a trigger

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

say it's fired

> after insert or update

is there a way tilling what really happened

e.g
insert into table x ....
then a the trigger fired says 'IT WAS AN INSERT'
update  x ....
then a the trigger fired says 'IT WAS AN UPDATE'

YES I CAN SPLIT THEM

Comment: [TG_OP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_table1() 
returns trigger
language plpgsql
AS $$
begin
    
    IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO tbl_status (state) values ('DELETE RECORD');
            RETURN OLD;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO tbl_status (state) values ('UPDATE RECORD');
            RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO tbl_status (state) values ('INSERT NEW RECORD');
            RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
   
    RETURN NULL; 
        
end;
$$;


CREATE TRIGGER trigger_log_table1
before INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE 
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_table1();
```